# Svelte web components - Export a class along with the components

Tags: javascript, web-component, es6-modules, svelte, custom-element

I started working with svelte and made a few reusable web components with it, but now I'm trying to use one of my classes that I've created as well.

`main.ts:`

```js
import MinimalTableManager from './components/MinimalTableManager.svelte';
import MinimalDataTable from './components/MinimalDataTable.svelte';
import {TableSort} from './models/tableSort';
```

Both elements are working just fine when I test them in my html:

```html
<script type="module">
    import * as tm from '/build/bundle.js'; 
    ...
</script>
```

And my main problem is that I'd like to use my `TableSort` class in the code as well, but right now I can't import it:

```
import {TableSort} from '/build/bundle.js'; 
...
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/build/bundle.js' does not provide an export named 'TableSort'
```

`rollup.config.js`:

```json
...
input: 'src/main.ts',
output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'app',
    file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
}
...
```

It's definitely a rookie mistake, but right now I have no idea how I should approach it correctly.

Comment: Is there a reason you're importing directly from your bundle instead of `'./models/tableSort'`?

Comment: Yes, I'm testing the component in my `index.html` not in Svelte, because I'd like to use it elswhere too.

Comment: Would you be able to post the bundled component? Could be the way it's compiled

Comment: Sure, this is the `bundle.js` : https://pastebin.com/HKfz6G46 and this is the `rollup.config.js`: https://pastebin.com/xMtwp2iv

Comment: The bundle has no exports. You might have to try a different [output format](https://www.rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputformat) instead of `iife`.

Comment: I had this issue with a couple of ordinary Svelte components and couldn't find a workaround. Ended up having to write an NPM script to copy the components into my bundle directory. This was for a published package, though. No idea if the same goes for a web-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Daniel_Knights I changed my output format in `rollup.config.js` from `iife` to `es` and now it works just fine.